# Heroku API Client returning my data instead of user's

Tags: heroku, oauth-2.0, heroku-api

I created an API Client on heroku on my account (hereinafter account A), and got it to install on another account (hereinafter account B) using the OAuth flow as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oauth#web-application-authorization

Started the flow on account B, accepted the permissions, which triggered the callback, where I exchanged the code to get the final tokens in the expected format:

```
{
  "access_token":"811235f4-16d3-476e-b940-ed5dfc7d6513",
  "expires_in":7199,
  "refresh_token":"036b9495-b39d-4626-b53a-34399e7bc737",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "user_id":"01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef",
  "session_nonce":"2bf3ec81701ec291"
}
```

( just to be clear, this is dummy data taken from the heroku documentation )

Up to here all was fine, however when I tried to use the token**, I got a very unexpected result: when I called the GET /apps endpoint, it returned the apps from account A instead of account B.

I can't make sense of why that would be the case, I have looked through the documentation profusely and can't find any explanation for that. If anyone has experienced this or has some explanation, I will gladly listen.

** by "use the token", I mean setting my header as `Authorization: Bearer {access_token}`, using python's `requests` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't related to heroku directly, but instead to a very sly linux file, `.netrc`. To make it brief, this file can be used by applications to store tokens in plain text. The very strange thing is that the python module `requests` uses it by default, overwriting the header you give it with one generated from that file, if there is a match.

To check whether you have the same issue, simply check the existence of the `.netrc` file in your home folder, or check the logs to verify if the headers sent are the ones you expected.